# Can i get different dates on different pages?

Tags: date

This is my template

```
\documentclass[article]{amsart}
\textheight 9.3in
\textwidth 6.5in 
\topmargin -1cm
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\oddsidemargin-.5cm \evensidemargin -.5cm 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{xypic}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\author{***}
\title{***}
\begin{document}
\date{30 september 2016}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

So, with this, I am getting the date 30th sep 2016 in first page in footnote.

I am writing notes of some course. I want to have dates mentioned for each lecture which are obviously different for each and that too in the footnote.

Please let me know if there is any way to do that.

Comment: separately, you should consider re-evaluating your template -- some of these constructs haven't been recommended for years.

Comment: @SeanAllred : So, what do you suggest in this case.

Comment: The template discussion is, last I checked, an ongoing conversation in the community. I generally hold to 'less is more' -- don't use templates and research what the best option is on a document-by-document basis. For the present question though -- your goal is unclear. What exactly do you want to happen with the date? What are you trying to do? Please edit your question for clarity :)

Comment: I have edited my question @SeanAllred

Comment: You can create your own command to put anything you like in a footnote. What is preventing you from doing that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command `\newdate` which will print at bottom of current page its argument in the style as the date on the title page.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\newdate}[1]{{%
   \let \@makefnmark \relax \let \@thefnmark \relax
   \def\@date {#1}\@footnotetext{\@setdate}}}
\makeatother
```

Example keeping your template as is:

```
\documentclass[article]{amsart}
\textheight 9.3in
\textwidth 6.5in 
\topmargin -1cm
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\oddsidemargin-.5cm \evensidemargin -.5cm 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{xypic}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\author{***}
\title{***}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\newdate}[1]{{%
   \let \@makefnmark \relax \let \@thefnmark \relax
   \def\@date {#1}\@footnotetext{\@setdate}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\date{30 september 2016}

\maketitle

\clearpage

New lecture

\newdate{\today}
\end{document}
```

Produces this at bottom of page 2:

[image]